# How can I create a comma-separated list of IDs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a `<ul>` that contains `<li>` elements, and I'd like to grab the IDs of these out and pass them on in a querystring to another page.

Like so:

```
<ul id="myList">
   <li id="first">First</li>
   <li id="second">Second</li>
   <li id="third">Third</li>
</ul>
```

into

```
first,second,third
```

Is there a neat way to do this? I've jQuery, so my brute-force probably-not-very-good-approach is to iterate using `each()` and build it that way. A bit scruffy, I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A short and neat way using [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var ids = $("#myList li").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get().join(",");
```

Comment: Works for me. Good stuff - thanks, it's always fun learning a new language/framework, and assistance like this is invaluable.